# Google Maps Directions URL with pin at Lat/Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a URL that will bring up Google Maps in Directions mode, starting at a long/lat, and showing a pin at that location.

I currently have the following working, but it doesn't drop a pin at my coordinates.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=35.17334,-106.55594&hl=en&sll=35.17334,-106.55594&sspn=28.132942,65.170898&t=m&mra=mift&mrsp=1&sz=5&z=18
```

https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=35.17334,-106.55594&hl=en&sll=35.17334,-106.55594&sspn=28.132942,65.170898&t=m&mra=mift&mrsp=1&sz=5&z=18

Is there a way to do what I have already done, but also have a pin at the long/lat?

Comment: There is a pin. just zoom out to see it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "pin" at the "B" location.  I assume you want a "pin" at the center, like this:

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=35.17334,-106.55594&daddr=35.17334,-106.55594&hl=en&sll=35.17334,-106.55594&sspn=28.132942,65.170898&t=m&mra=mift&mrsp=1&sz=5&z=18

[Description of parameters to Google Maps](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters)